# Как через .htaccess увеличить настройки php.ini?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Нужно записывать большие POST запросы.
Как правильно записать эти изменения в .htaccess? И можно ли так сделать вообще? php 7.2

```
upload_max_filesize=256M
max_execution_time=500
post_max_size=256M
max_input_vars=5000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но для этих целей есть **php.ini**

**.htaccess**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_vars 5000000
```

Сохраните настройки, создайте файл или выведите где-то в уже существующем файле функцию **phpinfo();**